# Remove bias in yticklabel in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

My problem is that when I plot y-values that are very close, matplotlib uses a bias for the yticklabel as seen in the picture below (+1.2 in the top left corner). [image: output image]

I don't want the bias as it does not reduce the length of the yticklabels. How can I remove the bias, so that it shows 1.2000010, 1.2000012...

Here is the code I used to generate the example:

```
from pylab import *

plot((0,1),(1.200001,1.200002))
show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest (and probably preferred) way of achieving this using the pyplot interface is using the supplied function `pyplot.ticklabel_format` in a way analogous to

```
from pylab import *

plot((0,1),(1.200001,1.200002))
ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
show()
```

The other proposed solutions give you more direct control, though.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just needed to adjust the formatting for your yticklabels, which you can do directly.  Using [this](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/major_minor_demo1.html) example, I got this to work:

```
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

plt.clf()
ax = subplot(111)
plot((0,1),(1.200001,1.200002))
majorFormatter = FormatStrFormatter('%.7f')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatter)
show()
```

Comment: your answer is more robust than mine I think.

Comment: @Yann, thanks.  Although, yours is good if you want to vary the formatting for different tick labels.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the text that is plotted at each ytick with the `yticks()` [method](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.yticks). Here's a block of code to do what you want:

```
from pylab import *

plot((0,1),(1.200001,1.200002))
ticks,ticklabels =  yticks()
newTickLabels = []
for tick in ticks:
    newTickLabels.append("%10.7f"%tick)
yticks(ticks,newTickLabels)
show()
```

I use `yticks()` with no parameters to get the ticks and corresponding labels, which I ignore. Then I make a new array of strings, one for each tick. Each label is the tick value in string format. You will have to adjust the formatting string `"%10.7f"` to get the desired look. Then I pass the ticks and tick labels back to the `yticks()` method to redefine them.

Here's the result:
[image]

Also looks like the y limits changed automatically; this can be adjusted with `ylim()`.